# Scala ElasticSearch indexing in relation to dynamically changing schema

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, indexing, apache-spark, mapping

I found the following code below  on CERN's website.
FYI: I am using spark 1.3
The example code is fantastic  when you know the schema of the dataset you want to index to elasticsearch.

However, could somebody point me in the right direction so that I can create a method as follows:

Pass in as an argument  the schema structure from external source (col name / datatype) (the hard bit) along with file name to be indexed (easy bit)?
Perform the schema mappings inside the function dynamically.

By having a method like this would allow me to generate a mapped and indexed dataset in ES.

Example Code:

```
    //import elasticsearch packages
    import org.elasticsearch.spark._

    //define the schema
    case class MemT(dt: String (link is external), server: String (link is external), memoryused: Integer (link is external)) 

    //load the csv file into rdd
    val Memcsv = sc.textFile("/tmp/flume_memusage.csv") 

    //split the fields, trim and map it to the schema
    val MemTrdd = Memcsv.map(line=>line.split(",")).map(line=>MemT(line(0).trim.toString,line(1).trim.toString,line(2).trim.toInt))

    //write the rdd to the elasticsearch
    MemTrdd.saveToEs("fmem/logs")
```

Thank you!

source:
https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/prasanth-kothuri/2016-05-integrating-hadoop-and-elasticsearch-%E2%80%93-part-2-%E2%80%93-writing-and-querying

Comment: a bit unclear, ES by default will generate schema accoring to docs you tried to index, isn't it what you want?

Comment: true, but column name not avail in header.  It is my understanding that elasticsearch can incorrectly set the data type by looking at only the first record. please quote me if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: See section labled "When to specify a custom mapping"..." this dynamic mapping generation comes with a few caveats: 1. Detected datatypes might not be correct...TimeStamp may be detected as long DataType..."   source:,https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-mapping-introduction. "

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted to achieve is to be able index directly into ES from a DataFrame,.
I required that the index mappings be driven from external schema source. Here is how I achieved that....

BTW: There is additional validation/processing that I have omitted, but this skeleton code should get those who require similar needs going....

I have included the following ES dependency in my build.sbt file

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark_2.10" % "2.3.3"
```

Comments welcome...

```
//Just showing the ES stuff
import org.elasticsearch.hadoop
import org.elasticsearch.spark._


//Declare a schema
val schemaString = "age:int, name:string,location:string"

//Fill RDD with dummy data
val rdd = sc.textFile("/path/to/your/file.csv")

val seperator = "," //This is seperator in csv 

//Convert schema string above into a struct
val schema =
  StructType(
  schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => 
  StructField(fieldName.split(":")(0),
  getFieldTypeInSchema(fieldName.split(":")(1)), true)))

  //map each element of RDD row to RDD with elements
  val rowRDDx =rdd.map(p => {
    var list: collection.mutable.Seq[Any] = collection.mutable.Seq.empty[Any]
    var index = 0
    var tokens = p.split(seperator)
    tokens.foreach(value => {
      var valType = schema.fields(index).dataType
      var returnVal: Any = null
      valType match {
        case IntegerType => returnVal = value.toString.toInt
        case DoubleType => returnVal = value.toString.toDouble
        case LongType => returnVal = value.toString.toLong
        case FloatType => returnVal = value.toString.toFloat
        case ByteType => returnVal = value.toString.toByte
        case StringType => returnVal = value.toString
        case TimestampType => returnVal = value.toString
        }
      list = list :+ returnVal
      index += 1
      })
    Row.fromSeq(list)
    })

//Convert the RDD with elements  to a DF , also specify the intended schema
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDDx, schema)

//index the DF to ES
EsSparkSQL.saveToEs(df,"test/doc")
```